# Comparing two different file types with same name in separate paths by iterating over the files

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to compare two different file extensions in different folders by iterating over the files present in those folders.

```
import os
from os.path import splitext
hpath = os.path.dirname(r'C:\Monarch')
dpath = os.path.dirname(r'C:\DOLV')

documents = set([splitext(filename)[0] for filename in dpath])
matches = [filename for filename in set(hpath) if splitext(filename)[0] in documents]
print (matches)
```

i tried this it only gives me  the result as `C, : \\`

I even tried this

```
from os import walk

hpath = r'C:\Monarch'
dpath=r'C:\DOLV'

h = []
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(hpath):
    h.extend(filenames)
    break
print(filenames)
d=[]
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(dpath):
    d.extend(filenames)
    break
print(filenames)
```

i am unable to compare them. I am able to print the name but unable to iterate over these file names and print a match.

What could i change to make it work?

Regards,
Ren.

Comment: `documents = set([splitext(filename)[0] for filename in d])
matches = [filename for filename in set(h) if splitext(filename)[0] in documents]
print (matches)` After adding this -  It worked

Answer (score 0):

Solved my issue.

```
from os import walk

hpath = r'C:\Monarch'
dpath=r'C:\DOLV'

h = []
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(hpath):
    h.extend(filenames)
    break
print(filenames)
d=[]
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(dpath):
    d.extend(filenames)
    break
print(filenames)

documents = set([splitext(filename)[0] for filename in d])
matches = [filename for filename in set(h) if splitext(filename)[0] in documents]
print (matches)
```